# install pine/alpine on Amazon EC2 linux

Tags: amazon-ec2, alpine-linux

Can someone tell me how to install pine or alpine (the text-based e-mail client) on an Amazon EC2 linux instance running Amazon Linux?

yum install pine
and
yum install alpine
did not work.

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=377634 based on this thread pine/alpine is no longer available on  Amazon Linux. Maybe a good time to switch to mutt?

Answer (score 2):

There is some support for pine and derivatives. You can install alpine on Amazon, with:

```
sudo yum install alpine --enablerepo=epel
```

Comment: Looks like AWS cut epel from the known repositories: `Error getting repository data for epel, repository not found`

Comment: Amazons directons to add the repository is here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-enable-epel/

Answer (score 0):

if it doesn't show up with a `yum search`, its unlikely that the packages are in the repository. You can try adding another repository that do have the packages. Centos/Redhat repositories work for the most part, but you might run into issues with dependencies.